# Assertion is not within its valid time range in AspNetCore Authentication OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, adal

I started receiving this error when trying to get a token for another application.

> Additional information: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials.
>   AADSTS50013: Assertion is not within its valid time range.

This started occurring after I upgraded from 1.0.1 to 1.1.0 of AspNetCore.  If I clear my cookies then this error goes away for a while.

Below is the code I use to get this token.  It's largely adapted from the code in the examples on GitHub.

```cs
var userObjectId = (user.FindFirst(AuthSettings.UserObjectIdClaimName))?.Value;
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
var authContext = GetAuthContext(userObjectId);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AuthSettings.ClientId, AuthSettings.ClientSecret);
var claimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

var token = claimsIdentity?.BootstrapContext as string;
if (token != null)
{
    try
    {
        authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(appId, credential,
            new UserAssertion(token)); // Error here
    }
    catch (Exception) { }

}
if (authResult == null)
{
    // Error no token in cache here
    authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(appId, credential,
        new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
}


return authResult.AccessToken;
```

You know what's interesting is that `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` that occurs if the first attempt fails never works because the Token cache is empty.  In my Startup I have code in `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` that goes ahead and stores a token in the token cache.  This callback is *never* executed.  Presumably if that first batch of code doesn't work then the fallback would handle it if this code did.

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    ClientId = authSettings.ClientId,
    Authority = authSettings.Authority,
    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = authSettings.PostLogoutUrl,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        SaveSigninToken = true
    },
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = authHelper.CreateOnRemoteFailureRedirectHandler("/Home/Error"),
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived =
            authHelper.CreateOnAuthorizationCodeRecievedAcquireAdditionalTokenHandler(new[] { CustomerManagerApi })
    },
});
```

This is the code that is currently not executing for `OnAuthorizationCodeRecieved`:

```
var userObjectId = (context.Ticket?.Principal?.FindFirst(AuthSettings.UserObjectIdClaimName))?.Value;
var clientCred = new ClientCredential(AuthSettings.ClientId, AuthSettings.ClientSecret);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AuthSettings.Authority, TokenCacheCreator(userObjectId));
var redirectAddressForAuthCode = new Uri(context.Properties.Items[OpenIdConnectDefaults.RedirectUriForCodePropertiesKey]);
authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.ProtocolMessage.Code, redirectAddressForAuthCode, clientCred, applicationId);

context.HandleCodeRedemption();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the `OnAuthorizationCodeReceived` was not fired because you set `ResponseType` to `OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken` which will not send the authorization code to the client.

> Additional information: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50013: Assertion is not within its valid time range.

And for this the error, please ensure that the access token is not expired before you send the token request using it for the user assertion.

Comment: I downgraded back to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization 1.0.0 and all my problems went away.  Also I realize now that the OnAuthorizationCodeReceived wasn't even necessary, that the example was using that to login to query GraphApi.  I think this is just a bug.

Comment: Please log an issue in the security repo :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem while exchanging user assertion to acquire Microsoft Graph API scope Token, I found that .Net Core Web API was allowing expired token  for 5 more minutes after its expiry, due to default 5 minutes Token validation clock skew property.

So I set the ClockSkew property of TokenValidationParameters to TimeSpan.Zero which blocked the expired token request and also resolved the assertion valid time range issue as well.